# iPhone communication with Windows C# App

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, xcode, ios4

I am create an iPhone app that needs to talk to a Windows C# app. The app will run as either a Service or Form Application.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Ideally exposing a service-type architecture would be best as I don't need a stateful connection (stateless is fine in this case).

Can a WCF service hosted by my app using a form of TCP binding be consumed by my iPhone? Or can an app host using httpBinding without the aid of IIS or some other web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

In my .NET windows service, I created WCF service bound using a WebHttpBinding endpoint. Doing so exposed my WCF services as JSON.

From the iPhone, using Objective-C, I used the ASIHTTPRequest and json-framework libraries to talk to and parse the JSON web service exposed by my .net app.

Answer (score 0):

To run WCF on iPhone you need MonoTouch. [Currently](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF), which isn't completely implemented.

I don't think it's a good idea.

Web Service are a better idea in my opinion. You can spawn a web service listener from your console/gui/service Windows C# application.

Comment: It actually isn't my intent to host a service from my iPhone. I only need my iPhone to communicate with my app, which will host the service.  My question is what do I host from my service? I know my iPhone can consume an http-bound WCF, but can it consume a TCP-bound WCF? Or do I need to bind it in some other way?

Comment: Yes, it can. But read that page about the issues you may encounter when using MonoTouch to develop the client, that's all.

Comment: I am able to consume a web service from my iPhone without using Mono. That's all I wanted to know. :) I posted info in my accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expose your C# application functionality as a ReSTful web service. More information on exposing WCF service is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx)

And there are project templates available for creating REST WCF service. Download the WCF REST starter kit.You can expose your service in XML/JSON format.

Then from your iPhone app, you may consume the web service exposed.

Comment: Hey Chaitanya - I wish you would have answered this a little earlier. :) I had found and posted my solution just before you posted this. Your linked items will provide useful for anyone in the future wishing to do this same thing.